# Any ideas on how to DRY code this navbar in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, dry

i'm creating a SPA using React and noticed that in the creation of my navbar there is going to be a lot of repetition. What i want is six components like this:

```
function Navbar() {
   return (
     <nav className="navbar">
       <div className="navbar-items">
         <Logo />
         <NavbarItem1 />
         <NavbarItem2 />
         <NavbarItem3 />
         <NavbarItem4 />
         <NavbarItem5 />
       </div>
     </nav>
   )
}
```

Now for the repetition part, every component is going to be basically this:

```
function NavbarItem1() {
   return (
     <div className="navbar-item">
       <button className="navbar-button">
         <svg class="navbar-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 80" x="0px" y="0px">
          <g>
            <path
              d="M52,7a5.006,5.006,0,0,0-5-5H7A5.006,5.006,0,0,0,2,7V56H4V7A3,3,0,1,1,8,9.816V7H6V62H48V11.9A5.009,5.009,0,0,0,52,7ZM8,60V12H46V60ZM47,10H10.974a4.9,4.9,0,0,0,0-6H47a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z" />
            <path
              d="M57,8a5.006,5.006,0,0,0-5,5V52.236l5,10,5-10V13A5.006,5.006,0,0,0,57,8ZM56,48.586,54.845,47.43,54,48.7V22h2Zm-1.846,3.486,1-1.5L57,52.414l1.845-1.844,1,1.5L57,57.764ZM60,48.7l-.845-1.267L58,48.586V22h2ZM60,20H54V18h6Zm-6-4V13a3,3,0,0,1,6,0v3Z" />
            <rect x="12" y="20" width="30" height="2" />
            <rect x="12" y="28" width="30" height="2" />
            <rect x="12" y="35" width="30" height="2" />
            <rect x="12" y="43" width="30" height="2" />
            <rect x="12" y="50" width="18" height="2" />
            <rect x="36" y="50" width="2" height="2" />
            <rect x="32" y="50" width="2" height="2" />
            <rect x="40" y="50" width="2" height="2" />
          </g>
        </svg>
        <span class="navbar-text">Item 1</span>
       </button>
     </div>
   )
}
```

So instead of creating six components who are basically the same, is there a less repetitive way of doing this or is this the normal way people create navbars using React?? Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: what is the difference between `NavbarItem1` and `NavbarItem2`?

Comment: People usually pass parameters to single component

Comment: You need to ask your self what parts are repeated and can be abstracted into a more general NavbarItem component. The parts that differ can be passed to each component instance as props or as children. After this you could also think about a way to abstract the data that differs into an array or object and loop over it for example.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to inform that the difference between each `NavbarItem` is the SVG icon and span text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the parts that differ between each navbar item are the icon and its text content, you can extract the icons into their own components, then just pass the icon component and the text via props:

```
// Pass className via props so the NavbarItem can set it
function NoteIcon({ className }) {
  return (
    <svg
      className={className}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 64 80"
      x="0px"
      y="0px"
    >
      <g>
        <path d="M52,7a5.006,5.006,0,0,0-5-5H7A5.006,5.006,0,0,0,2,7V56H4V7A3,3,0,1,1,8,9.816V7H6V62H48V11.9A5.009,5.009,0,0,0,52,7ZM8,60V12H46V60ZM47,10H10.974a4.9,4.9,0,0,0,0-6H47a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z" />
        <path d="M57,8a5.006,5.006,0,0,0-5,5V52.236l5,10,5-10V13A5.006,5.006,0,0,0,57,8ZM56,48.586,54.845,47.43,54,48.7V22h2Zm-1.846,3.486,1-1.5L57,52.414l1.845-1.844,1,1.5L57,57.764ZM60,48.7l-.845-1.267L58,48.586V22h2ZM60,20H54V18h6Zm-6-4V13a3,3,0,0,1,6,0v3Z" />
        <rect x="12" y="20" width="30" height="2" />
        <rect x="12" y="28" width="30" height="2" />
        <rect x="12" y="35" width="30" height="2" />
        <rect x="12" y="43" width="30" height="2" />
        <rect x="12" y="50" width="18" height="2" />
        <rect x="36" y="50" width="2" height="2" />
        <rect x="32" y="50" width="2" height="2" />
        <rect x="40" y="50" width="2" height="2" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
}

function NavbarItem({ icon: Icon, children }) {
  return (
    <div className="navbar-item">
      <button className="navbar-button">
        <Icon className="navbar-icon" />
        <span className="navbar-text">{children}</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="navbar-items">
        <Logo />
        {/* Pass the correct icon component, and the text via children */}
        <NavbarItem icon={NoteIcon}>Item 1</NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem icon={OtherIcon}>Item 2</NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem icon={AnotherIcon}>Item 3</NavbarItem>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! I edited the answer to fix some mistakes, namely `class`->`className` and `{ Icon }` -> `{ icon: Icon }`